# Database failed to process. Divide by zero error encountered running sp_BlitzIndex

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-blitzindex

I am seeing a divide by zero message while running `sp_BlitzIndex`.  I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5775.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2) (VM)

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzIndex, Line 1535
SIOP database failed to process. Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Comment: which options did you run it with?

Answer (score 3):

That's my bug! It's in the statistics gathering portion. If you search for the line:

```
CASE WHEN si.rowmodctr > 0
```

Replace the whole case expression with this:

```
CASE WHEN si.rowmodctr > 0 THEN CAST(si.rowmodctr / ( 1. * NULLIF(si.rowcnt, 0) ) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 1))
                                     ELSE si.rowmodctr
                                END AS percent_modifications,
```

The best place to file bug reports for Blitz* scripts is [over here](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be related to the bug listed on the github issues page [#525](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/525). That was fixed 5 days ago. Go ahead and pull the new committed code and it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Hah. Looks like you had an easier time finding it than I did. I'm so bad at GitHub.

Comment: I am too, I just follow your project pretty close. Helps me learn by monitoring other projects and doing. Trying to see if I would do it differently. Additionally, the filter on the issues page helps a bunch :)